# OpenPyXl removing formulas on load

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use OpenPyXL to

- Open an .xlsx file
- Read a cell that I know contains a number
- Write a different number to that cell
- Save the result to the same or different named .xlsx file

However even if I only perform the first and last steps the resulting .xlsx file has all formulas removed. The simplest version of my code goes like:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename=file_path, data_only=False, guess_types=False)
wb.save(file_path_new)
```

However even without changing anything I still lose all the formulas. I have tried different values for the options. My biggest problem is that only yesterday, the full code (including reading and writing a numerical cell) was working and the saved result had the new number in that cell (when viewed in excel).

**I updated from 1.8.5 to 2.0.2 at some point but can't remember if this was before or after the original code worked.**

Comment: I'd suggest updating to 2.1.x and trying again. If you still have problems please submit a bug report with a sample file.

Comment: I can see that you are using the data_only=False option to read in the fomulae. However I do not believe that this option is available in openpyxl for save. Maybe this should be a feature request

Comment: I ran the above code with 1.8.5 and the problem has disappeared. However my ultimate goal was to have excel reevaluate its formulae with the changed value and read the results, which doesn't seem possible. I'm going to cut excel out of the work flow.